# Позиционирование в DataGrid

Tags: avalonia

Есть DataGrid в котором изменяется строка и если изменяется сортированный столбик то необходимо спозиционироваться на новое положение строки . Все нормально если новое положение находится ниже текущей позиции , а когда выше тогда

```
    this.list1.ScrollIntoView(this.list1.SelectedItem, this.list1.Columns[0]));
```

не работает совсем , строка выделяется и остается в невидимой области . Есть обход этой проблемы ?